# Tensorflow: ValueError: Expected non-integer, got <dtype: 'int32'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, valueerror

I'm just starting with Tensorflow and when I call `m.fit(input_fn=lambda: self.input_fn(train_data), steps=train_steps)`, then I receive the following error.

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 161, in _input_from_feature_columns
    transformed_tensor = transformer.transform(column)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 882, in transform
    feature_column.insert_transformed_feature(self._columns_to_tensors)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py", line 991, in insert_transformed_feature
    self.sparse_id_column.insert_transformed_feature(columns_to_tensors)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py", line 572, in insert_transformed_feature
    name="lookup")
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lookup/lookup_ops.py", line 1018, in index_table_from_tensor
    "integer" if dtype.is_integer else "non-integer", keys.dtype))
ValueError: Expected non-integer, got <dtype: 'int32'>.
```

In the feature columns that I pass to `fit()`, there are only `int32`and `int64`, but that should not be the problem, should it?

Comment: can you provide a sample of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could happen that you use categorical features with `tf.SparseTensor` but your feature columns contain `int32`.

In this case just convert your integer columns into string, for example like this:

```
# using Pandas
for f in categorical_features:
    df_train[f] = df_train[f].astype(str)   
    df_test[f] = df_test[f].astype(str)
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!